# How to set a mailmessage as an attachment on another mailmessage

Tags: c#, vb.net, mailmessage

I have two mailmessages, I want to attach one two the other in vb.net or c#.

How do I do this?

I've had a look at msdn's pages for MailMessage and Attachment but can't wrap my head around it.
I've managed to send other files as attachments, do I do it in the same way? If so what mime type/MediaTypeNames would I use?

I've tried searching online (including SO) but all results are for attaching files etc (which are streams - I don't think mailmessage is?)

I'm sure it must be possible and I think I must be overthinking it, I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

**Use Case**

Just to clarify why I want to do this, its essentially a simple method to see the email exactly as it was generated, without sending it to the recipient(s) but preserving that metadata. Unit tests are well and good but being able to see the exact email in a browser (and show it to stakeholders) is invaluable.

Comment: Yes, you link it the same way, or forward it.. and you can make it a stream if you wished

Answer (score 0):

Given your use case I would suggest a different approach (I use it myself to test SendMail): send your mail in a local directory as an eml.

Then you can use an email client to see the mail, or just explore it as a textfile to check the raw structure.

How to do it? Just configure your SMTP client class to deliver the mail localy when you want to test:

```
    SmtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory;
    SmtpClient.PickupDirectoryLocation = directoryDelivery;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: added use case to original question

Comment: Updated my answer for your use case ;)